# to show $\{n^2f(\frac{1}{n})\}$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is analytic , $|f(\frac{1}{n})|\le |\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}|\forall n$, we need to show $\{n^2f(\frac{1}{n})\}$ is bounded.
Could any one give me hint only for the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant $|f(n^{-1})|\leqslant n^{-3/2}$, otherwise $f(z)=z$ is a counter-example.

We have $f(0)=0$, hence write $f(z)=zg(z)$. Use Schwarz lemma to show that $|g(z)|\leqslant C|z|$ for some constant $C$. Deduce the result.